# Removing HTML tags without /text().extract()

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

To start, I'm very new at all this so get ready for some jacked up code from me copying/pasting from all kinds of sources.

I'm looking to be able to remove any html code that scrapy returns. I've got everything storing in MySQL with no issues, but the thing I can't get to work yet is removing a lot of '< td >' and other html tags. I initially just ran with /text().extract() but randomly it would come across a cell that was formatted this way:

```
<td>    <span class="caps">TEXT</span>  </td>
<td>    Text    </td>
<td>    Text    </td>
<td>    Text    </td>
<td>    Text    </td>
```

There isn't a pattern to it that I can just choose between using /text or not, I'm looking for the easiest way that a beginner can implement that will strip all that off.

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.loader import XPathItemLoader
from scrapy.contrib.loader.processor import Join, MapCompose
import html2text
from scraper.items import LivingSocialDeal


class CFBDVRB(BaseSpider):
    name = "cfbdvrb"
    allowed_domains = ["url"]
    start_urls = [
        "url",
    ]

    deals_list_xpath = '//table[@class="tbl data-table"]/tbody/tr'
    item_fields = {
        'title': './/td[1]',
        'link': './/td[2]',
        'location': './/td[3]',
        'original_price': './/td[4]',
        'price': './/td[5]',
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        selector = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

        for deal in selector.xpath(self.deals_list_xpath):
            loader = XPathItemLoader(LivingSocialDeal(), selector=deal)

            # define processors
            loader.default_input_processor = MapCompose(unicode.strip)
            loader.default_output_processor = Join()

            # iterate over fields and add xpaths to the loader
            for field, xpath in self.item_fields.iteritems():
                loader.add_xpath(field, xpath)

            converter = html2text.HTML2Text()
            converter.ignore_links = True
            yield loader.load_item()
```

The converter = html2text was my last attempt at removing it that way, I'm not entirely sure I implemented it correctly but it didn't work.

Thanks in advance for any help you would like to give and I also apologize if I'm missing something easy that a quick search could pull up.

Comment: I don't know the first thing about Scrapy but have you looked into [Feed exporters](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/topics/feed-exports.html#topics-feed-exports) ? It looks like it's the way to export the retrieved data in the format you want.

Comment: well I didn't figure out how to use BeautifulSoup to do it, which I really would like to figure that out for future use. But, by adding a //text() it allowed it to select all the text which is what I wanted

Comment: @AaronGOUZIT Feed Exports are for getting items out of Scrapy into a more permanent storage option.  Usually, you don't want the feed exporter handling cleaning code unless it's relevant to how it's going to be stored (that should be outside it's scope).  An item loader is much better suited to this purpose, as it's design was to scrub/modify the data as it gets loaded into the item.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The authors of Scrapy use a bunch of this functionality in their `w3lib` which is part of/included with Scrapy.

*Based on your code, you're using a pretty dated version of Scrapy (pre 0.22).  I'm not sure exactly what's available to you, so you may need to import from `scrapy.utils.markup` instead*

If you have the variable `my_text` that has your HTML text in it, do the following:

```
>>> from w3lib.html import remove_tags
>>> my_text
'<td>    <span class="caps">TEXT</span>  </td>\n<td>    Text    </td>\n<td>    Text    </td>\n<td>    Text    </td>\n<td>    Text    </td>'
>>> remove_tags(my_text)
u'    TEXT  \n    Text    \n    Text    \n    Text    \n    Text    '
```

There's a lot of additionally functionality for fixing up/converting html/markup with w3lib (code available [here](https://github.com/scrapy/w3lib/blob/master/w3lib/html.py)).

As this is just a function, it will be pretty easy to incorporate into your item loader, and will be more lightweight than using BS4.

Comment: Absolutely perfect, all I had to do was import the w3lib.html and changed the input processor from 'unicode.strip' to 'remove_tags' and it worked.

Comment: With `MapCompose()`, you don't have to remove `unicode.strip`, just add in the remove_tags first: `MapCompose(remove_tags, unicode.strip).  Or, add it second, if that better suits how you want the content processed.  It allows multiple callables to be provided.

Comment: Unfortunately this leaves scripts and styles around.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way to do it is using **BeautifulSoup**. Even the Scrapy Documentation recommends it.

Imagine you have a variable called "html_text" with this html code inside:

```
<td>    <span class="caps">TEXT</span>  </td>
<td>    Text    </td>
<td>    Text    </td>
<td>    Text    </td>
<td>    Text    </td>
```

Then you could use this to remove all the htmltags:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'html.parser')
just_text = soup.get_text()
```

Then the variable "just_text" will contain just the text:

```
TEXT
Text
Text
Text
```

I hope this solves your problem.

You can see more examples and the guide to install it (easier than Scrapy) at:
[BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Good Luck!

EDIT:

Here you have a working example with the html you proposed:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_text = """
<td>    <span class="caps">TEXT</span>  </td>
<td>    Text    </td>
<td>    Text    </td>
<td>    Text    </td>
<td>    Text    </td>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'html.parser')

List_of_tds = soup.findAll('td')

for td_element in List_of_tds:
    print td_element.get_text()
```

Please, note that you need to be using **BeautifulSoup 4**, which you can install following [these instructions](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-beautiful-soup). If you have it, you can just copypaste that code and see what it does to other html and modify it to satisfy your needs.

Comment: I'm trying to implement this, but I keep getting a object of type 'variable' has no len()

Where exactly should this be used at? I tried it in my spider at first and then I tried it in my pipelines file before the data gets sent to the data base and both resulted in the same error.

Comment: I have edited my response with a working code example. I have tested it and it works.